# How to make a new array out of only even numbers?

Tags: java, arrays, string, integer

Basically, I am trying to make an entirely new array of a new length that contains only the even `ints` in an array of integers.
However, I am getting an `index out of bounds error`. Can you help me find what I did wrong?

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
public class findevens {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(evens(new int[]{4,8,19,3,5,6})));
    }

    public static int[] evens(int[] arr) {
        //create new array by determining length
        //of even number ints
        int length = 0;
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
        {
            if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
                length++;
            }   
        }   
        int[] result = new int[length];
        //add even ints to new array
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
        {
            if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
                result[i] += arr[i];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: In your second loop you need an extra counter variable for inserting into the new array as you can't just copy to the same index. (eG declare `int insertionCounter = 0;` before the loop and use `result[insertionCounter++] = ` for setting elements)

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can you streams:

```
    int[] array = {1, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int[] even = IntStream.of(array).filter(item -> item%2 == 0).toArray();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(even));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a new variable to keep track of the current `result` index (let's say, `j`):

```java
public static int[] evens(int[] arr) {
        int length = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
                length++;
            }   
        }   
        
        int[] result = new int[length];
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
                // Access result with `j` and update its value
                result[j++] = arr[i];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a new `index` variable for the `result` array and your assignment is also wrong as instead of assigning you are adding the `even` number to the result array element.

```java
        int j = 0;
        int[] result = new int[length];
        // add even ints to new array
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
        {
            if (arr[i] % 2 == 0)
            {
                result[j++] = arr[i];
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you are using **i** for the result array AND the original array. You should only increment the result array inside of the IF (when you find an even number) otherwise, you go out of bounds due to i (the original arr) being a larger size than the result array.

```
public static int[] evens(int[] arr) {
    //create new array by determining length
    //of even number ints
    int length = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
    {
        if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
            length++;
        }   
    }   
    int[] result = new int[length];
    //add even ints to new array
    int resultCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
    {
        if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
            result[resultCount] += arr[i];
            resultCount++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply when you want to assign a value to `result[]` you do it with the index in the array `arr`, `0, 1` and `5`. You just have to declare an auxiliary `int aux = 0;` variable before second loop and increment according to `arr[i] % 2 == 0` so `true`

```
result[i] += arr[i];
```

a

```
 int aux = 0;
 result[aux++] += arr[i];
```

Complete code

```
public class findevens {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(evens(new int[]{4,8,19,3,5,6})));
}

public static int[] evens(int[] arr) {
    //create new array by determining length
    //of even number ints
    int length = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
            length++;
        }   
    }   
    int[] result = new int[length];
    int aux = 0;
    //add even ints to new array
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
            result[aux++] += arr[i];
        }
    }
    return result;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't really know how long the resultant array will be you can copy them to the front of the current array.  Then use the final location as the count of values.

```
int[] input = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int k = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i] % 2 == 0) {
        input[k++] = input[i];
    }
}
int[] evens = Arrays.copyOf(input, k);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(evens));
```

Prints

```
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to filter even numbers [using the `Stream` API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams.html) and return the result as an array.

```
Arrays.stream(arr)
      .filter(n -> n % 2 == 0)
      .toArray();
```

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(evens(new int[] { 4, 8, 19, 3, 5, 6 })));
    }

    static int[] evens(int[] arr) {
        return Arrays.stream(arr).filter(n -> n % 2 == 0).toArray();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[4, 8, 6]
```

### What went wrong with your code:

`result.length` is 3 and therefore in `result[]`, the maximum index you can access is 2 (i.e. `result.length -1`) whereas your second loop counter goes up to 5 (i.e. `arr.length - 1`) and you are using the same counter to access elements in `result[]` resulting in `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

If you want to do it in your own way, you need to use a separate counter for `result[]` e.g.

```
int[] result = new int[length];
//add even ints to new array
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
{
    if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
        result[j++] = arr[i];
    }
}
```